# Time Frame of the Current Workweek in Datetime

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, node-mysql

**Javascript Time Frame**

---

I'm trying to write a Node app that grabs data entries from MySQL based on a time frame equal to the beginning and end of the current work week.

---

Here's the Node-MySQL query:

```
function retrieveSales(){

    connection.query('select * from sales_entries where date BETWEEN ? AND ?',
    timeFrame,

    function (err, rows, fields) {

        var sales = new Array();

        for (x=0;x<rows.length;x++){
            sales.push(rows[x]);
        }

        return sales;

    });
}
```

where `timeFrame` is an array of two dates in `datetime` format, which is the second-specific time data-type that MySQL offers as a default. ( 31/12/2010 03:55 AM )

---

The problem is, I've never worked much with dates in JS. So I have two questions:

1. Would it be better to record a different date format to the database, or is datetime fine?
2. How should I generate this array with values equal to the beginning of the first day of the current work week (monday) and end of the last day of the current work week (friday) respectively?

---

**The Fiddle**

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7AXU/1/), including three functions; `retrieveSales`, which performs the query, `dateTime()`, returning the current time in datetime format, and `retrieveData` which is the main function that will call all necessary queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would say use the ISO8601 format in your database and everywhere else and http://momentjs.com/docs/ to deal with al your dates.

Still, you can work with a date time string like you have, just parse into 'a moment' using a custom format string.

```
// parse from string, see docs for format
var t = moment('31/12/2010 03:55 AM', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A"); 

// ISO-8601
t.format()

// and back to that MySQL format
t.format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A");
```

You can do a lot of computerations on `t` (comparisons, mutations, formatting), just check the momentjs docs.

Edit: more specifically, filling `timeFrame` could be as follows:

```
// from sun to saterday of this week
var timeFrame = [ moment().days(0).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A")
                , moment().days(6).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A") ];

// or since method.days() wraps around, this is monday-sunday
var timeFrame = [ moment().days(1).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A")
                , moment().days(7).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A") ];
```

HTH

Comment: Teach a man to fish, right? Thank you. This tool is very helpful.

Comment: added some stuff to help you along